# Android install an apk from URL

Tags: android, download, apk

My application verify if there are a new version of my application (my application is not into play store) and download automatically the apk file into sdcard/download. Then I would like to start the installation and I use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "file.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

but it show the pop up "Parse Error:There is a problem parsing the package"

Into my AndroidManifest I have put the permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error message. The root of my problem was that I was saving the `apk` I downloaded to my `application data` directory instead of a `sdcard`. By saving to `/sdcard/myprog.apk` I was able to do the install without any issues.

Since I was able to get the install to work from a web browser download, it was a matter of figuring out where those downloads go, then when I download programmatically to save in the same location.

I found the following very useful for my update process: [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) then I used something similar to what you have to do the install.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to manually install the file, the error problem parsing the package comes, when an apk has a corrupt manifest file. Check if manual installation of the file you downloaded works in the first place.

Comment: Yes it start but when I click on install button it show "An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed"

Comment: I have resolved, the problem was that I installed the application with Eclipse and then I download from web the apk and install it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "file://" before your file's path.
something like this:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + filepath), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```