# Android update an app in the background

Tags: android

This app is not on the google play. I can update in manually from a server, but I d like to update it automatic, like in the google play, it is updating automatically in the bg, and show it in Notification bar.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Yes,** For Updating your Data/APK in Background you can Use GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) Push Notification.

For this you can Ask user at starting of app for Updating your Data/APK from server when they will get changed. Now When Data Changes from Server you can simply send push notification to device and Update your Data in Background. and if APK then Download it and installed it in device.

you will get Further Details [Google Cloud Messaging for Android | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Hope it will Help.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a service that runs periodically, and checks the server if an update is available (check the timestamp of the APK would be one way to check this).

Then download the APK.  Install it, and send a notification.

This is a complicated thing to accomplish, and probably not something you would want to do yourself if you can help it.  (Why isn't it in the Play Market?)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715737/android-install-an-apk-from-url?rq=1) on how to install apk via url or maybe you want to install a local apk file [already downloaded to the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

How to determine that there's an update? Poll your server on regular intervals, or maybe use Google Cloud Messaging or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates), In-app updates works only with devices running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher, and requires you to use Play Core library 1.5.0 or higher.
Types:

- Flexible
- Immediate

Note: When you publish your app an Android App Bundle, the maximum allowed compressed download size of an app using in-app updates is 150MB. In-app updates are not compatible with apps that use APK expansion files (.obb files).

***Check for update availability***

```
// Creates instance of the manager.
AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context);

// Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

// Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
          // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
          && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
              // Request the update.
    }
});
```

***Start an update***

```
appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
    // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
    appUpdateInfo,
    // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
    AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
    // The current activity making the update request.
    this,
    // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
    MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

The type of update you request determines the next steps you need to take. To learn more, read the section about how to either [Handle an immediate update](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#immediate_flow) or [Handle a flexible update.](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#flexible%20flow)

***Get a callback for update status***

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (myRequestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (myRequestCode != RESULT_OK) {
      log("Update flow failed! Result code: " + resultCode);
      // If the update is cancelled or fails,
      // you can request to start the update again.
    }
  }
}
```

For more information on the implementation of code checkout link shared

Comment: how will you install it in background?

Comment: @KiranBablani You need the flexible update, for more info check this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#flexible_flow

Comment: Yes i've read it but its only downloading in background. Once you call 
completeUpdate(), it starts a fullScreen UI and app is restarted. My question was can i avoid Fullscreen ui and install in background as well??