# Android Set Permission on Downloaded APK

Tags: android, permissions, apk

I'm running into a problem similar to: [Android install an apk from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715737/android-install-an-apk-from-url)

I created a program which downloads the files from a url, and then tries to install it. If I download the apk directly from a web browser and run it, I'm able to install the program no problem.

When I try to do it programmatically, I get the file downloaded properly and the file size matches what is on my server. However I get the `Parse error: There was a problem parsing the package` message. When I look at the file from the `DDMS` I have `-rw-------` for the file permission that was downloaded.

Does anyone know if I need to change the permissions on that file before I run it, e.g. Are there different permissions if you download from a browser versus a different program? If not, any ideas on what I could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, and am going to leave the question up as a reference, in case anyone has simliar issues.

The issue was that I was saving the `apk` to my application data directory instead of my `sdcard`. When I saved the file to the `sdcard` I was then able to start the install programmatically without any issues.

Comment: flag it as the asnwer please.